# Android App User Authentication with PHP

Tags: php, android

first time poster here.

I'm a college student working on an Android app right now that collects location data from users and stores them on a server for later retrieval.  I've got the front end running fairly nicely (collects the data and has the ability to store it locally or send it via POST data to my php server).

Now I just need to figure out how to implement a user authentication system on the back end.  I'm really not storing very much data, just user credentials and the location data linked to it, so I've kind of been shying away from using a full-fledged CMS or some sort of framework for the back end.  Like I said though, I'm still a student and I'd be all ears to any suggestions.

My initial idea is to just use the filesystem.  When a new user creates an account, a new directory is created with their user name and their password is hashed and stored in a separate directory as a file named something along the lines of newuser.pw.  When a user tries to login, their credentials are checked against this file and if they match, they are granted access to their directory holding their location data which they can then browse via an interface on the phone.

My question to all of you is, is this system too simple.? Could it ever be secured and if so, how would you go about doing that?  If this sounds like a security nightmare, what sort of back end framework/CMS would you suggest?

Comment: So 100,000 users = 100,000 directories ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Yeah, basically.  I guess I could have a master directory for all users and individual files for each, but I don't know how much better 100,000 files would be than directories.

Comment: I think that it would be better to use a database for such end.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this before. You can collect the data to .TXT on your server. Or store data in TXT on device and upload it periodically. What datas you'll store ?

Comment: Location data (latitude and longitude coordinates) collected at certain intervals over a specified amount of time.  When the user turns the app on, it sends the device's location data to the server every couple of minutes until the user either turns the app off manually or a specified time has elapsed.  This can all be stored as text, but I'd like to be able to group these tracking sessions together. I only want users to be able to access their own data though.  Is this something that a database would be better at handling?

Comment: I understood now. Database can do what you want.